# How to convert dataframe into multiple json objects?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I would like to ask help on how to creating nested json from dataframe.
I have a dataframe

```
 name     value  xAxis1    yAxis1  xAxis2    yAxis2           lineStyle
0  LCL  0.205512       0  0.205512     200  0.205512  {'type': 'dashed'}
1  UCL  0.327907       0  0.327907     200  0.327907  {'type': 'dashed'}
2   CL  0.269737       0  0.269737     200  0.269737  {'type': 'dashed'}
```

The problem is I want to separate into two json objects.
Here is my attempt:

```
[
    {
        "name":x['name'],
        "xAxis":x['xAxis1'],
        "yAxis":x['yAxis1'],
        "lineStyle":x['lineStyle']} for _, x in global_line.iterrows()
]
```

It gives the result:

```
[{'name': 'LCL',
  'xAxis': 0,
  'yAxis': 0.20551206141285452,
  'lineStyle': {'type': 'dashed'}},
 {'name': 'UCL',
  'xAxis': 0,
  'yAxis': 0.327906798236399,
  'lineStyle': {'type': 'dashed'}},
 {'name': 'CL',
  'xAxis': 0,
  'yAxis': 0.2697369344707218,
  'lineStyle': {'type': 'dashed'}}]
```

The response that I want :

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "name": "LCL",
                "xAxis1": 0,
                "yAxis1": 0.205512,
                "lineStyle": {
                    "type": "dashed"
                }
            },
            {
                "xAxis2": 200,
                "yAxis2": 0.205512
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "name": "UCL",
                "xAxis1": 0,
                "yAxis1": 0.327907,
                "lineStyle": {
                    "type": "dashed"
                }
            },
            {
                "xAxis2": 200,
                "yAxis2": 0.327907
            }
        ]
    ], 
...
}
```

Any help and suggestion would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with join in list comprehension:

```
a = df[['name','xAxis1','yAxis1','lineStyle']].to_dict(orient='records')
b = df[['xAxis2','yAxis2']].to_dict(orient='records')

d = {"data": [[x,  y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]}
```

---

```
{
    'data': [
        [{
            'name': 'LCL',
            'xAxis1': 0,
            'yAxis1': 0.205512,
            'lineStyle': {
                'type': 'dashed'
            }
        }, {
            'xAxis2': 200,
            'yAxis2': 0.205512
        }],
        [{
            'name': 'UCL',
            'xAxis1': 0,
            'yAxis1': 0.327907,
            'lineStyle': {
                'type': 'dashed'
            }
        }, {
            'xAxis2': 200,
            'yAxis2': 0.327907
        }],
        [{
            'name': 'CL',
            'xAxis1': 0,
            'yAxis1': 0.269737,
            'lineStyle': {
                'type': 'dashed'
            }
        }, {
            'xAxis2': 200,
            'yAxis2': 0.269737
        }]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I can't write a post. I need help with Pandas. I want to join two Dataframes with a date condition.  Join df1 and df2 column index 'serial_numb' and add a new column from df2 to 'date'. condition: serial_numb For example if it finds two or more rows I need the date of only the first one which is greater than the date of serial_numb of df1.  photo example:  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-application-3b4b3.appspot.com/o/2023-02-23_123323.png?alt=media&token=b7d19aa3-6e13-4806-afc9-3bb27575e777

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - I think you need [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: No, it can't help me.

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - Do you use `by` parameter also? What is your not working code?

Comment: I'll try now and I'll give you an exact answer.

Comment: can you see photo? https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-application-3b4b3.appspot.com/o/2023-02-23_141507.png?alt=media&token=67cdcd00-4502-4e4a-9d12-0c3dfd3b3275

Comment: And you can take a simple example from here:         df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SERVICE_DEVICE_SN':["3743353259F74146", "3743353259EEC455", "3743353259EED583", "5A544547C1E1D261", "3043343933CE1AFB"],
    'CLOSE_DAY': ["10/10/2022",  "25/10/2022", "30/10/2022", "20/10/2022", "15/10/2022"]
})

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'SERVICE_DEVICE_SN':["5A544547C1E1D261", "5A544547C1E1D261", "5A544547C1E1D261", "5A544547C1E1D261", "5A544547C1E1D261"],
    'CLOSE_DAY': ["10/10/2022",  "25/10/2022", "30/10/2022", "20/10/2022", "15/10/2022"]
})

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - what is expected output?

Comment: output:   I want the first date from df2 that is greater than the date from df1, that date is the first greater than date from df2.  merge/vlookup must be made with SERVICE_DEVICE_SN.

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - I think how looks expected DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will try to write a post from someone else.

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - Working on it ;)

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - Not sure if correct, can you try `pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('CLOSE_DAY'), df1.sort_values('CLOSE_DAY'), on='CLOSE_DAY', by='SERVICE_DEVICE_SN')` ?

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - Also check `allow_exact_matches=False` parameter, maybe need  `strictly less-than / strictly greater-than`

Comment: Unfortunately merge_asof doesn't work. In the df, I want a new column where there will be a date from df1, with the appropriate condition, which I wrote above.   I will test allow_exact_matches

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili - It was reason why ask for expected ouput ;) I cannot test if correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Another option with keys separation:

```
ax2 = ['xAxis2', 'yAxis2']  # secondary keys
main_keys = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(ax2)]
[[{k:d[k] for k in main_keys}, {k:d[k] for k in ax2}] for d in df.to_dict('records')]
```

---

```
[[{'name': 'LCL',
   'value': 0.205512,
   'xAxis1': 0,
   'yAxis1': 0.205512,
   'lineStyle': {'type': 'dashed'}},
  {'xAxis2': 200, 'yAxis2': 0.205512}],
 [{'name': 'UCL',
   'value': 0.327907,
   'xAxis1': 0,
   'yAxis1': 0.327907,
   'lineStyle': {'type': 'dashed'}},
  {'xAxis2': 200, 'yAxis2': 0.327907}],
 [{'name': 'CL',
   'value': 0.269737,
   'xAxis1': 0,
   'yAxis1': 0.269737,
   'lineStyle': {'type': 'dashed'}},
  {'xAxis2': 200, 'yAxis2': 0.269737}]]
```

Comment: Hello, Roman can you help me? unfortunately I can't write a post. I need help with Pandas. I want to join two Dataframes with a date condition. Join df1 and df2 column index 'serial_numb' and add a new column from df2 to 'date'. condition: serial_numb For example if it finds two or more rows I need the date of only the first one which is greater than the date of serial_numb of df1. photo example: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-application-3b4b3.appspot.com/o/2023-02-23_123323.png?alt=media&token=b7d19aa3-6e13-4806-afc9-3bb27575e777

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili, I need a testable fragments of both of your dataframes. Ask someone to post a question with those fragments and a meaningful description.

Comment: can I send you my dataframe in linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

Based on of your code (but using [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) that is more efficient than `iterrows`):

```
{'data': [[{k: getattr(t, k) for k in ['name', 'xAxis1', 'yAxis1', 'lineStyle']},
           {k: getattr(t, k) for k in ['xAxis2', 'yAxis2']},
          ] for t in global_line.itertuples()]}
```

Output:

```
{'data': [[{'name': 'LCL',
    'xAxis1': 0,
    'yAxis1': 0.205512,
    'lineStyle': "{'type': 'dashed'}"},
   {'xAxis2': 200, 'yAxis2': 0.205512}],
  [{'name': 'UCL',
    'xAxis1': 0,
    'yAxis1': 0.327907,
    'lineStyle': "{'type': 'dashed'}"},
   {'xAxis2': 200, 'yAxis2': 0.327907}],
  [{'name': 'CL',
    'xAxis1': 0,
    'yAxis1': 0.269737,
    'lineStyle': "{'type': 'dashed'}"},
   {'xAxis2': 200, 'yAxis2': 0.269737}]]}
```